# update a column and save it back to dataset in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I m working on a football dataset which has a few columns. There is one column called TimeUnder and the datatype of the column is int64. I want to append the unit 's' to all the values in the column and save it back to the dataset.

I converted the column to a string datatype and modified appending a 's' to each value in the column TimeUnder. I saved the modifications to a new csv file

```
import pandas as pd
football=pd.read_csv("Football_dataset.csv")
football1=football['TimeUnder'].astype(str) + 's'
football1.to_csv("football_modified.csv")
```

```
football_m=pd.read_csv("football_modified.csv")
football_m.head()
```

But the new modified csv only has the modified column, but I want all of the previous columns in the dataset along with the modified column 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you are modifying the column and creating a separate dataframe from it and writing that to csv.

Instead, you need to modify the column in the original df and write it to df.

**Change this `football1=football['TimeUnder'].astype(str) + 's'` to:**

```
football['TimeUnder']=football['TimeUnder'].astype(str) + 's'
```

Then write to csv:

```
football.to_csv("football_modified.csv")
```